# Compiling sass with npm scripts - node-sass returns EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-sass

Following [this writeup](http://beletsky.net/2015/04/npm-for-everything.html) I am trying to write a script to compile my sass into css using node-sass.

This is my package.json scripts part:

```
  "scripts" : {
    "prestart" : "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "start" : "npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch sass:watch test:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* src tools",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "sass": "node-sass src/assets/**/*.scss src/assets/css",
    "sass:watch": "npm run sass -- --watch",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "test": "mocha --reporter progress tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\""
  },
```

now when I run `npm run sass` trough the terminal I get the following message:

> > Introduction@1.0.0 sass /Users/shooshte/PersonalProjects/introductionReact
> >     node-sass src/assets/**/*.scss src/assets/css
>
> Rendering Complete, saving .css file... Error: EISDIR: illegal
>   operation on a directory, open
>   '/Users/shooshte/PersonalProjects/introductionReact/src/assets/css'

Both of the directories are created. What am I doing wrong?

If you need more info, just comment or you can also view the [GitHub](https://github.com/Shooshte/introductionReact) repo.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`EISDIR` means you are trying to run an operation on a file, but you gave a directory (folder).

```
"sass": "node-sass src/assets/**/*.scss src/assets/css/*.css"
```

update the code to target a `.css` file instead of a folder.